# Need help on unchecked operations java

Tags: java, generics

I am learning algorithms myself, and I tried to implement `LinkedList` in `Java` with generic types from scratch. I had a version with `Object` which works well, but when I updated it with generic types, it gives warnings. Can anybody help where does the "unchecked or unsafe operations" come from?

```
class LinkedListGeneric <T> {
    private Node<T> head; 
    private int size;

    public LinkedListGeneric() {
       head = null;
       size = 0; 
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add (T data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node<T> (data);
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            Node<T> temp = new Node<T> (data);
            search(size).setNext(temp);
            size++;
        }
    }

    public void add (T data, int position) {
        if (position > size + 1 || position <= 0) {
            System.out.println ("error.");
            return;
        }
        Node<T> temp = new Node<T> (data);
        if (position == 1) {
            temp.setNext(head);
            head = temp;
            return;
        }
        Node<T> prev = search(position - 1);
        temp.setNext(prev.getNext());
        prev.setNext(temp);
    }

    public void delete (int position) {
        if (position > size || position <= 0) {
            System.out.println ("error.");
            return;
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            size--;
            head = head.getNext();
            return;
        }
        Node<T> prev = search(position - 1);
        prev.setNext(prev.getNext().getNext());
        size--;
    }

    public T getValue (int position) {
        if (position > size || position <= 0) {
            System.out.println ("error.");
            return null;
        }
        Node<T> temp = search(position);
        return temp.getData();
        //return search(position).getData();
    }

    public int searchData(T data) {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        int position = 1;
        boolean flag = false;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.getData() == data) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp = temp.getNext();
                position++;
            }
        }
        if (flag) return position;
        else return -1;
    }

    public void print() {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        int position = 1;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println("Node " + position + ": " + temp.getData());
            temp = temp.getNext();
            position++;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> search (int position) {
        Node temp = head;
        while (position > 0) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;
        public Node() {
           this.data = null;
           next = null; 
        }

        public Node(T data) {
           this.data = data;
           next = null; 
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the warning? Do you understand what the warning means?

Comment: Well, which lines does the compiler tell you it comes from?

Comment: At a glance?  Delete `<T>` from `private class Node<T>`, it's nested inside a type which already defines a `T`, so you're just shadowing.

Comment: "Unchecked or unsafe" refers to the fact that you have defined `Node<T>` but are calling `Node` (no `<T>`). Also, you shouldn't genericify both your `List` and `Node` with the same type variable (use `T2` or something for your `Node`)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. The warnings are gone.

Comment: Remember to click the check mark next to the answer you believe was the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is your `Node.getNext` call is returning a `Node` instead of a `Node<T>`. This is equivalent to the method returning `Node<Object>` instead of the generic type.

So, you should change:

```
public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

to

```
public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although sbochin's answer will fix some of your warnings, doing the following will fix all of them:

1. Replace all instances of `T` within your `Node` class, including the one in the class declaration, with `T2`.
2. Change the return of `getNext` to `Node<T2>`
3. Change the argument type in `setNext` to `Node<T2>`.
4. Change the type of `temp` in `search` to `Node<T>`.
5. You might also want to add an `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` to `public Node()` since that also generates a compiler warning.

You might also want to make your `Node` class a static class as none of it's methods depend on the `LinkedListGeneric<T>` object it is in.

Completely alternatively, you could just get rid of the type parameter from `Node`, which gets rid of all your warnings except the unused warning. You'd have to keep your class nonstatic however.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions of "static" or not using type parameters from the Node class. Much better than what I thought when doing coding.